# PHP: File retriever file gives error 403 only with a certain directory and subdirectories

Tags: php, file

So I have this PHP file which retrieves files, and displays them in a table with name, size, date modified, etc. It works with all other directories. However, when I go into my `windows` folder (`/windows`), where the file (`get.php`) is located at `/windows/files/get.php`. I can't access any directories inside `/windows`. Whenever I try to open a directory in `/windows`, the `get.php` page is throwing the error:

> GET http://www.example.com/windows/files/get.php?sd=/windows/files 403 (Forbidden)

I changed the permissions for only one of the subdirectories, then immediately changed it back. I have another file retriever with the same PHP, only different display, and it can retrieve subdirectories of `/windows` perfectly fine. I tried copying `get.php` to the home location `/`, and it worked perfectly, so I assumed the problem is that it's located in one of the subdirectories. If so, why would this be the problem, and how could I fix it without moving the file? Thanks.

Comment: What are the directory permissions? How did you change them?

Comment: I changed it back. I had previously changed a subdirectory `/windows/example` to 751, but changed it back immediately once I saw this problem.

Comment: Many factors may cause 403, such as web server configuration or just file permissions. You'd better paste the detailed log here.

Comment: No errors are thrown in the log. Only error is in the console, which I posted above.

Comment: Checked all file perms, they're the same, and I didn't change any other config. I assume the problem is that it's in that folder, read above.

Comment: Might be that the directory owner is different?

Comment: Again, I changed nothing.

Comment: I think I know the problem. I have `index.php` in `/windows/files`, and it has an iframe that displays `get.php`.

Comment: I tried changing the permission for that folder to 777, still doesn't work.